# Python Flask submit button problems

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

The "send..." button is not working, index page is running, drop-down menu ok, but when I click the "send..."  nothing happen. (Result.html is ok, but empty of course) Any idea, what is the problem?

I've got these .py file:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_wtf import Form
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/result/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    vehicle = request.form.get('wine')
    year = request.form.get('year')
    return render_template('result.html', vehicle=vehicle, year=year)
```

And two .html of course. index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<h1>Submitting</h1>

<form action="/result" method="POST">
    <label for="wine">wine</label>
    <select id="wine" name="wine">
      <option>red</option>
      <option>white</option>
      <option>rose</option>
    </select>

    <label for="year">Year</label>
    <select id="year"name="year">
      <option>1972</option>
      <option>1999</option>
      <option>2010</option>
    </select>
</form>

<br>
<button type="submit" value="submit">send...</button>
</body>
</html>
```

The result.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        {{ vehicle }} {{ year }}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: After I changed "vehicle" to "wine" in all places, the problem is the same: "send..." not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your HTML with this HTML. you need to put submit button inside form tag to make it work.

```
<body>
<h1>Submitting</h1>

<form action="/result" method="POST">
    <label for="wine">wine</label>
    <select id="wine" name="wine">
      <option>red</option>
      <option>white</option>
      <option>rose</option>
    </select>

    <label for="year">Year</label>
    <select id="year"name="year">
      <option>1972</option>
      <option>1999</option>
      <option>2010</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" value="submit">send...</button>

</form>

<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to put your `button` in `form` tag ?

```
<form action="/result" method="POST">
    ...
    <button type="submit" value="submit">send...</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That was the problem. :-)